# gcc/Ubuntu: Finding the disk path to the library used at linkage

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, path, linkage

I want to figure out where resides the dynamic third-party library on my disk. How to do this? My problem is that I get successful linkage, but I do not understand from where. I used verbose mode of gcc but I only get the paths used. I know the name of the library, but the search on disk fails to find it. The so even loads successfully in runtime. Is there any tool like process monitor in Windows?

Thanks,
Vadim

Follow-up:

Thanks for great answers, but I am still stuck. My library does not shows up in the ldd, but the code linked and runs successfully. How can such a think happen? As a reference, I build the same project for 32-bit and their all works as expected: unless I add a soft-link to my library it neither links nor runs. Clearly, I have two versions of my library (for 32 and for 64 bit). Library name is libfftw3.so.3

vadim@ubuntu64:~/meg_software/SAM_code/Mains/SAMtime$ ldd SAMtime64

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff097ff000)

libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff7898d4000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff789515000)

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff789beb000)
```

vadim@ubuntu64:~/meg_software/SAM_code/Mains/SAMtime$ ldd SAMtime

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7739000)

libfftw3.so.3 => /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3 (0xf753c000)

libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7510000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7365000)

/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf773a000)
```

Comment: Try `ldd </path/to/your/executable`.

Comment: Thanks for great answers, but I am still stuck. My library does not shows up in the ldd, but the code linked and runs successfully. How can such a think happen? As a reference, I build the same project for 32-bit and their all works as expected: unless I add a soft-link to my library it neither links nor runs. Clearly, I have two versions of my library (for 32 and for 64 bit). Library name is libfftw3.so.3

Comment: Precisely `ldd </path/to/your/executable>/<name of executable>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by installing realpath.

```
sudo apt-get install realpath
```

and then

```
akshayy@ubuntu:/usr/bin$ realpath python
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

it will return location where symlink points.

Answer (score 0):

@devnull's hint is correct: `ldd` will do the trick. I'm writing it as an answer in order to elaborate a bit.

```
ldd path/to/executable
```

And the path can be either relative or absolute. Also, the path can be to another shared library, not necessarily an executable. Also note the lack of `<` I don't know where @devnull got that from.

---

EDIT:

PS: I don't know how/where you have been searching for the library, but you may find `locate` useful. Eg,

```
$ locate libc.so.6
/home/.../Dropbox/tag_localization/3rd_party/lib/libc.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib32/libc.so.6
```

If the library was installed recently, you might need to update `locate`'s  cache with

```
$ sudo updatedb
```